# How to pack the elements of product of matrix multiplication back

Tags: python, list, matrix

A beginner to Python, I am trying to work my way into understanding how to do things in as Pythonic a way as possible.

I am attempting to write a function to which returns result of matrix multiplication of 2 matrices. here's what I came up with:

```
 def matmul(a,b):
     c = zip(*b)
     def element(i,j):
         return reduce(lambda x,y: x+y,map(lambda x:x[0]*x[1],zip(a[i],c[j])))
     print [element(i,j) for i in range(len(a)) for j in range(len(c))]
```

The list that I am printing contains the product of each element of the product, but it's a list not a matrix.

```
>>> a = [[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> b = [[1,1],[1,1]]
>>> matmul(a,b)
[3, 3, 7, 7] 
>>> a = [[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]]
>>> b = [[1,8,7],[8,7,11],[7,8,2]]
>>> matmul(a,b)
[16, 23, 20, 32, 46, 40, 48, 69, 60]
```

`[3,3,7,7]` should be actually be represented as `[[3,3],[7,7]]` and
`[16, 23, 20, 32, 46, 40, 48, 69, 60]` as `[[16, 23, 20],[32, 46, 40],[48, 69, 60]]`

But, I am not able to think of a concise way to pack the list back into 2D.

How would I easily and concisely go about doing so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very close, you just need to use a nested list-comprehension with `zip(*)`:

```
zip(*[[element(i,j) for i in range(len(a))] for j in range(len(c))])
```

A re-factored version of your code:

```
from operator import mul
from itertools import starmap, izip, imap

def matmul(a, b):
     c = zip(*b)
     def element(row):
         # or   [sum(map(mul, row, col)) for col in c]  
         # or   [sum(imap(mul, row, col)) for col in c]  
         return [sum(starmap(mul, izip(row, col))) for col in c]
     print [element(row) for row in a]
```

---

Most concise way will be use [`numpy.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
>>> b = np.matrix([[1,1],[1,1]])
>>> a * b
matrix([[3, 3],
        [7, 7]])
```

---

In Python 3.5(not released yet) we will be able to use the `@` operator on Python lists to do [matrix multiplications](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0465/).

Comment: Thanks! Damn! Shouldn't have given up so easily...clearly I still need to work on list-comprehension and zip. They are really powerful. Using Numpy would be the simplest/best choice in 'real-world' project indeed!

Comment: Definitely much more pythonic and elegant. And easier to understand. Thanks a third time. I had a long chat about itertools and operators the other day. Your code is great example of why they are more pythonic.

Comment: `zip(*[[sum(map(mul,row,col)) for row in a] for col in zip(*b)])` is where it's at really :). In your refactored solution, which one is most efficient ? starmap-izip or map ?

Comment: @anu You can time them using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module. There's no need to use `zip(*)` now, if you want a one-liner then: `[[sum(starmap(mul, izip(row, col))) for col in c]  for row in a]` is what you need. `map` will create an unnecessary list in Python 2 that' why I used `starmap`, you can also use `itertools.imap`. IMO `imap` should be fastest one here for bigger lists, but you should still time them.